# changing text color of a Menu control in JavaFX with FXML/CSS

Tags: css, menu, javafx-2, fxml

I want to change the text color of the *Menu* control in **JavaFX**. Currently, the background color of the whole *Menu Bar* is set to white and the default text color for displaying *Menu*-s is also white, so I cannot see the actual control, therefore I want to set the text color of the *Menu* ("File") to black. How do I do that?

Here's the **FXML** portion:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <MenuBar id="modBar" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="122.0" styleClass="modBar">
      <menus>
        <Menu id="modItem" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="modItem" text="File" />
      </menus>
      <stylesheets>
        <URL value="test.css" />
      </stylesheets>
    </MenuBar>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here's the **CSS** part:

```
.modBar
{
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.modItem
{
    -fx-color: black;
}
```

This doesn't work ("File" still remains **white**). What am I doing wrong? Also, another thing is that I cannot seem to apply *anything* with CSS to **.modItem** - it sort-of works in **Scene Builder**, but disappears once previewed (also the "Stylesheets" selector is missing on all *Menu*-s in SB).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, think I have found the answer. What I did was extract **caspian.css** out of **jfxrt.jar** (the default **CSS** theme **JavaFX** uses) and inspect everything related to *Menu*-s:

```
.menu .label
{
    -fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

This will influence **all** *Menu* controls.

---

By the way, there was a particular *build* of **Scene Builder** that might come of interest - **b42**, this had an additional **CSS** menu that exposed internal styles of controls/elements, so customizing turns into a straightforward operation (without the need of prior manual extraction of the applied style).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you set the id attribute - doesn't that mean you can only access them via
    #modBar
or
    #modItem
???

I'm also quite new to JFX2 (about a month) and unfortunatelly in all my years as a Java developer I never needed to play around with css, so it's just an assumption.