# Change MenuBar color in Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx-2, menubar, scenebuilder

How does one change the color of a JavaFX 2 `MenuBar` in JavaFX Scene Builder? I want to make it the same color as the menu bar in the Scene Builder. CSS´s `color` and `background-color` doesn't seem to help.

I'd also be happy to know the color of the Scene Builder menu bar (in hexadecimal or decimal RGB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fx-background-color` css property to set the menu bar background color.

Regarding the Scene Builder menu bar background color, you can use:

```
-fx-background-color: 
    derive(#e0e0e0, -0.291),
    linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        derive(#e0e0e0, 0.353) 0%,
        derive(#e0e0e0, -0.058) 100%
);

-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
```

I extracted these css "coordinates" from Scene Builder jar, located at `SceneBuilderInstalationRoot/lib/SceneBuilder.jar`. In the jar, its on the package `com.oracle.javafx.authoring.css_stylesheets`, file SceneBuilderTheme.css. This css file uses a named constant `-fx-color` which I inferred to have value `#e0e0e0`.

Comment: Now the text for the `Menu`s are white. How can I change the color?

Comment: Take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051936/changing-text-color-of-a-menu-control-in-javafx-with-fxml-css)

Answer (score 3):

You can find help about css directly in scene builder : on the menu View > Show CSS analyser

here you will can see that the menu bar use the class `.menu-bar` and have this `-fx-background-color` set with some color. So now you know that you have to put on the style of your MenuBar

```
-fx-background-color : thecoloryouwant
```

And that it.

Comment: `Show CSS analyser` doesn't show up under `View`, but thanks anyway.